# Publish ASP.NET website by FTP in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, ftp, filezilla

I am beginner in ASP.NET and trying to publish my first website by using `FTP(FileZilla)`. I have web hosting and domain name but After following this method:

> **To publish your web application using FTP:**
>
> 1. Open the project in Visual Studio 2013. Click Build > Publish. That 
>      will bring up the "Publish Web" dialog box.
> 2. Change the "Publish Method" to FTP. Server: Enter your FTP URL. Example:
>      ftp.YourHostedDomain.com
> 3. In the Site Path field, enter the
>      subdirectory you wish to publish the application to (for example: /Subdirectory).
> 4. If you want to publish to the root directory. Leave 
>      the Site path empty.
> 5. In username field, enter the FTP user name
>      found    in Control Panel.
> 6. In the password field, enter the FTP
>      password.
> 7. Click "Next" to determine the web.configuration you
>      will publish.
> 8. Click "Publish."

I am able to publish it in my `ftp.YourHostedDomain.com` but it is not working well, when I visit my Destination Url it is showing me that site, from where I have purchase this domain and hosting instead of my website which I have published. I spend lots of time for it, Please suggest me what should I do?

Comment: If your hosting provider supports WebDeploy, then publishing will be much easier. One of the things I found when looking for somewhere to host, is that not everyone supports FullTrust, which is generally required for .net 4.6.

Comment: @Neil Yes, they are provided me WebDeploy... and I purchase it from one.com which is fully Trust able site around me...

Comment: Great, so no need to FTP then, just use WebDeploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, MVC web applications will publish or update their database on first run.  Have you tried copying your project to the correct folder on the hosting site and pulling up the home page?